# Dummify column of lists in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tidyr

Given the following structure:

```
df <- structure(list(checkPointAdditionalData_ignorePermissions = list(
    list("READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_CONTACTS", "READ_PHONE_STATE", 
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION", "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION", 
        "READ_CALL_LOG"), list("READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_CONTACTS", 
        "READ_PHONE_STATE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION", 
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION", "READ_CALL_LOG"), list("READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", 
        "READ_CONTACTS", "READ_PHONE_STATE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", 
        "READ_CALL_LOG"), list("READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_CONTACTS", 
        "READ_PHONE_STATE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_CALL_LOG"), 
    list("READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_CONTACTS", "READ_PHONE_STATE", 
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_CALL_LOG"), list("READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", 
        "READ_CONTACTS", "READ_PHONE_STATE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", 
        "READ_CALL_LOG"), list("READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_CONTACTS", 
        "READ_PHONE_STATE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_CALL_LOG"), 
    list("READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_CONTACTS", "READ_PHONE_STATE", 
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_CALL_LOG"), list("READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", 
        "READ_CONTACTS", "READ_PHONE_STATE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", 
        "READ_CALL_LOG"), list("READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_CONTACTS", 
        "READ_PHONE_STATE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_CALL_LOG")), 
    L_ignore_perm = c(7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I want to "tidy" it to put all the lists contents as additional columns and dummify it:

Desired result:

```
    READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE READ_CONTACTS READ_PHONE_STATE 
                        1             1                1
                        1             1                1
                        1             1                1
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION 
                     1                    1                      1
                     1                    1                      1 
                     1                    0                      0
    READ_CALL_LOG
                1
                1
                1
```

etc.. for each row.

Please advise how to do this, I am trying to play with `tidyr` functions.
I completely understand that the flow should be `union` of all possible members of the lists, add them as column names, apply `ifelse` for each column to put `1/0` as value.

Isn't there a function that does it simply and efficiently?

I have already done the following:

```
df %>%
  dplyr::select(checkPointAdditionalData_ignorePermissions) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(L_ignore_perm = lengths(checkPointAdditionalData_ignorePermissions)) %>% 
  unnest(checkPointAdditionalData_ignorePermissions) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(checkPointAdditionalData_ignorePermissions = unlist(checkPointAdditionalData_ignorePermissions))
```

and trying the `dummies` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df$checkPointAdditionalData_ignorePermissions %>%
  map_df(data.frame) %>% 
  set_names(map(., levels)) %>%
  mutate_all(function(x) if_else(is.na(x), 0, 1))

   READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE READ_CONTACTS READ_PHONE_STATE WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION READ_CALL_LOG
1                      1             1                1                      1                    1                      1             1
2                      1             1                1                      1                    1                      1             1
3                      1             1                1                      1                    0                      0             1
4                      1             1                1                      1                    0                      0             1
5                      1             1                1                      1                    0                      0             1
6                      1             1                1                      1                    0                      0             1
7                      1             1                1                      1                    0                      0             1
8                      1             1                1                      1                    0                      0             1
9                      1             1                1                      1                    0                      0             1
10                     1             1                1                      1                    0                      0             1
```

Comment: Can you please explain it with more details? @h-1